# How to create a progress pie chart using plotly from a percentage value?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

If there is a variable like

```
x = 80
```

or a dataframe like

|  | progress |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 80 |

Then how do I create a chart like the one below
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names' : ['progress',' '],
                   'values' :  [progress, 100 - progress]})

fig = px.pie(df, values ='values', names = 'names', hole = 0.5,
             color_discrete_sequence = ['FC0080', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']
            )
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data
progress = 80
df = pd.DataFrame({'names' : ['progress',' '],
                   'values' :  [progress, 100 - progress]})

# plotly
fig = px.pie(df, values ='values', names = 'names', hole = 0.5,
             color_discrete_sequence = ['red', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']
            )

fig.data[0].textfont.color = 'white'
# fig.show()
fig.show()

f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: When progress = 40 and progress = 60, it'll plot same, due to the implicit sort=True. Instead of   ' color_discrete_sequence = ['red', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']'  , replace   'color_discrete_map = {"progress":"red"," ":'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}  )'